# Spring Boot 2 - Actuator Metrics Endpoint not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

In my Spring Boot App (2.0.0.M7) application.properties I set

```
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
```

However, when i hit

```
localhost:8080/actuator/metrics
```

I get 404.

Whats the solution?

Answer (score 86):

I would like to enhance the OP's answer with more information as I struggled a bit before finally stumbling upon this solution and there seem to be lots of confusion about changes to actuator behavior with Spring Boot 2

**What hasn't changed**

You need to include a dependency to *spring-boot-starter-actuator*

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If you want to access actuator endpoints via HTTP, you also need to add a dependency to *spring-boot-starter-web*

So your pom dependencies will look like below

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Changes introduced in Spring Boot 2**

1. Endpoints like `/health`, `/metrics` etc. are **no longer** available at the default root context. They are available from now on at
   `http://{host}:{port}/actuator`.
   Also, it doesn't matter whether your application's all other endpoints begin with some other context such as `/hello` -- actuator is available at `/actuator` and not at `/hello/actuator`.
2. Response from `/actuator` endpoint is by default [HATEOAS](https://spring.io/understanding/HATEOAS) enabled. Prior to Spring Boot 2, this was the case only [if HATEOAS is on the classpath and explicitly enabled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoint-hypermedia) in `application.yml`
3. To make an actuator endpoint available via HTTP, it needs to be both **enabled and exposed**.

   **By default:**

   - only the `/health` and `/info` endpoints are exposed, regardless of Spring Security being present and configured in your application.
   - all endpoints but `/shutdown` are enabled (though only `/health` and `/info` are exposed)
4. If you want to expose all of the endpoints (not always a good idea), you may do so by adding `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*` to `application.properties`. Don't forget to quote the wildcard if you're using yml-configurations.
5. Old properties starting with `endpoints.xyz` are deprecated in favor of properties starting with `management.xyz`

For a full documentation, see [official doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html) and also the [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide)

Comment: Starting from spring-boot2, now is `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*`

Comment: In case of yaml configuration you need to quote the wildcard, otherwise it will fail to parse: `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: '*'`

Comment: @Timi I agree, answer is amended

Comment: I wander what is the use of the actuator if so much has been removed or disabled by default. I have the actuator in my project and the only thing useful is the health status and even that is questionable. Something is running or not and if down then the heartbeat disappears. The info url creates an empty json. So why use it at all?

Comment: Nothing much is removed. Sensitive endpoints are disabled by default for some good reason

Comment: this makes sense but it annoys me the latest documentation says the opposite https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints-enabling-endpoints

Comment: @Chad they're enabled but not exposed by default, which is what the docs say.

Answer (score 29):

Add the following line to your `application.properties` file:

`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=metrics`

That's all.

Comment: Also `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*` worked for me

Answer (score 12):

What worked for me is the following (in YAML format) working with spring boot 2 release:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: info, health, metrics
  metrics:
    export:
      atlas:
        enabled: false
```

also specific documentation can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints-enabling-endpoints)

Comment: When I use this, the /metrics endpoint works, but shows only the keys, not the values.  What up???

Comment: yes this is how it works you then select a metric to display instead of having all metrics displayed in a messy single page, also useful for other apps like prometheus or atlas to read the metrics

Answer (score 8):

You need to add the below props in your `application.properties` file. I had the same issue until I added the below props.

```
management.endpoints.beans.enabled=false
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue upgrading from Spring Boot 1.5.15 to 2.1.4

Needed to modify the original dependency for the Spring Boot actuator in my `pom.xml` from:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

notice the addition of the word `starter` in the `artifactId`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for sharing! What is the difference between `enabled` and `exposed`? Thanks!

Comment: This was rather infuriating since either one seems to build fine -- but the first silently fails to work.

Answer (score 7):

"*" has a special meaning in YAML, so be sure to add quotes if you want to include (or exclude) all endpoints, as shown in the following example:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

Answer (score 4):

According [micrometer docs](https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/prometheus) .Spring Boot 2.0.x supports Micrometer out of the box via Spring Boot Actuator.
The endpoint **metric** is disabled by default, in line with Spring Boot 2’s litmus test that any endpoint that potentially exposes sensitive data about an application should be disabled by default. It can be enabled by setting:

> management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: metrics

Navigating to `/actuator/metrics` displays a list of available meter names.

To access them, use something like this:
http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/jvm.memory.used

Comment: Only this one worked for me for ```application.properties``` by specifying ```management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=metrics```

Answer (score 3):

Okay i found the solution. I have added another line in application.properties

```
management.endpoints.web.expose=*
```

However, securing the actuator endoints is important

Read here: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html

Answer (score 1):

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: "/"
      exposure:
        include: '*'
```

it should works like that. `*` means expose all endpoints

Answer (score 1):

Adding the below property in application.properties solved the issues for me:

```
management.health.defaults.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=metrics` in `application.properties` to expose `/actuator/metrics` with HTTP.

---

ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html

ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints

Actuator endpoints let you monitor and interact with your application. Spring Boot includes a number of built-in endpoints and lets you add your own. For example, the health endpoint provides basic application health information.

**Each individual endpoint can be `enabled` or `disabled` and `exposed` (made remotely accessible) over `HTTP` or `JMX`. An endpoint is considered to be available when it is both enabled and exposed.** The built-in endpoints will only be auto-configured when they are available. Most applications choose exposure via HTTP, where the ID of the endpoint along with a prefix of /actuator is mapped to a URL. For example, by default, the health endpoint is mapped to /actuator/health.

ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.enabling

**By default, all endpoints except for shutdown are enabled.**

ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.exposing

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration works for me

server.servlet.context-path=/travel
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

Then you need to add context path: 
http://localhost:8080/travel/actuator/metrics/

Answer (score 0):

As @senseiwu mentioned, Unlike the previous versions, Actuator in spring boot 2 comes with most endpoints disabled.
Would we want to enable all of them, we could set

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Alternatively, we could list endpoints that should be enabled.

You can easily use hal-browser which is a useful UI, mapped to "/" path by adding following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In the hal-browser you need to type /actuator to see all endpoints.
It has been tested in Spring Boot 2.3.0.M2 and works perfectly.
You can learn more in the following links:

[Spring REST and HAL Browser](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-hal)

[Spring Boot Actuator](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators#boot-2x-actuator)

Answer (score 0):

Put here the full config for micrometer. The following one is working fine for me. I use it for ELK stack

```
management:
  metrics:
    enable:
      jvm: true
      all: true
    export:
      elastic:
        enables: true
        step: 10s
        index: micrometer-${spring.application.name}
        host: http://localhost:9200
      simple:
        enabled: true
    distribution:
      percentiles-histogram:
        http:
          server:
            requests: true
      sla:
        http:
          server:
            requests: 100ms, 400ms, 500ms, 2000ms
      percentiles:
        http:
          server:
            requests: 0.5, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99
  endpoint:
    metrics:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
```