# How to enable all endpoints in actuator (Spring Boot 2.0.0 RC1)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I moved to Spring Boot 2.0.0 RC1 from 1.5.10 and I am stuck with actuator in the latest version. How can I enable expose and enable all actuator endpoints?

The only endpoints that get exposed are:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/actuator",
      "templated": false
    },
    "health": {
      "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/actuator/health",
      "templated": false
    },
    "info": {
      "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/actuator/info",
      "templated": false
    }
  }
}
```

This is my `application.properties` files. Any ideas?

```
#The three first ones seem to be obsolete
endpoints.configprops.enabled=true
endpoints.beans.enabled=true
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true

management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=true
management.endpoints.sensitive=false
management.endpoints.enabled=true

management.endpoint.configprops.enabled=true
management.endpoint.beans.enabled=true
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48670785/2702730 for a very detailed response

Comment: As mentioned in the link @senseiwu posted. Old properties starting with `endpoints.xyz` are deprecated in favor of properties starting with `management.xyz`. So yes using any recent version of SpringBoot you should rely on `management.endpoints` properties and remove root `endpoints` configurations.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

With Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC**1**, actuator endpoints must be 1) enabled and 2) exposed.

By default, all endpoints but `shutdown` are enabled and only `health` and `info` are exposed.

In your case, the following should work:

```
management.endpoints.web.expose=*
# if you'd like to expose shutdown:
# management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
```

Note that this changes (again!) as of Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC**2**:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
# if you'd like to expose shutdown:
# management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
```

In doubt, [the dedicated migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#endpoints) is always up-to-date with the latest changes.

**Edit**

For easy copy and paste, here's the `yaml´ versions - as of Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC**2**:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC**1**:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      expose: "*"
```

Comment: I tested the solution for RC1 and it works perfectly. Upvoting. Many thanks.

Comment: In `application.yml` I had to enter it as `include: "*"`

Comment: For me single quotes worked like  include: '*'

Answer (score 2):

I will add that for Spring Boot 2 the actuator security has been changed (for 1.X the security for actuator has separate configuration what often cause problems when it mixes with user configuration). For Spring Boot 2.X the actuator won't have separate security config. According to Spring documentation:

> For security purposes, all actuators other than /health and /info are disabled by default. The management.endpoints.web.expose flag can be used to enable the actuators. If Spring Security is on the classpath and no other WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is present, the actuators are secured by Spring Boot auto-config. If you define a custom WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, Spring Boot auto-config will back off and you will be in full control of actuator access rules.)