# Spring Actuator endpoints giving 404 error, except for health and info

Tags: spring, spring-boot

To better understand Spring Actuator, I have created a sample Spring Initializr project, with only the following two dependencies:

1. Spring Boot Actuator
2. Spring Web

In my `application.properties` file I enabled all the endpoints that are disabled by default for web applications (as per https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints).

> It was my expectation that I would be able to access all the actuator endpoints.  However, I am getting `404s` for all endpoints except http://localhost:8080/actuator/health and http://localhost:8080/actuator/info.

My application.properties file is as follows:

```
# Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints

management.auditevents.enabled=true
management.endpoint.beans.enabled=true
management.endpoint.caches.enabled=true
management.endpoint.conditions.enabled=true
management.endpoint.configprops.enabled=true
management.endpoint.env.enabled=true
management.endpoint.flyway.enabled=true

# true by default
#management.endpoint.health.enabled=true

management.endpoint.heapdump.enabled=true
management.endpoint.httptrace.enabled=true

# true by default
#management.endpoint.info.enabled=true

management.endpoint.integrationgraph.enabled=true
management.endpoint.jolokia.enabled=true
management.endpoint.logfile.enabled=true
management.endpoint.loggers.enabled=true
spring.liquibase.enabled=true
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.endpoint.mappings.enabled=true
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
management.endpoint.scheduledtasks.enabled=true
management.endpoint.sessions.enabled=true
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
management.endpoint.threaddump.enabled=true
```

Comment: I created a spring boot project from start.spring.io with actuator and copy/paste your application.properties and it's work well. Are you sure to start your application on port 8080 or hav you error in your startup logs ?

Comment: check question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48900892/how-to-enable-all-endpoints-in-actuator-spring-boot-2-0-0-rc1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you need to specify endpoints to expose after enabling them.

From the docs 2.2:

`*` can be used to select all endpoints. For example, to expose everything over HTTP except the env and beans endpoints, use the following properties:

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude=env,beans