# How to enable spring-actuator to collect metrics from multiple applications

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a pod which consists of multiple containers each have an application running. How do I enable actuator to fetch metrics from these applications. I couldn't find a way to do this.

There are four micro services running in the pod on different ports say 8082, 8080, 8081, 8083. But the actuator is scraping the metrics only from the micro service running on 8080(default port).

I tried adding application properties indicated in code section to all properties. but it didn't work.  Here is the application.property content:

```
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true  
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*  
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true  
management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=true  
management.metrics.use-global-registry=true  
management.server.port=8888
```

Expected output: I should be able to see the metrics from each applications using /metrics endpoint.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot 2 - Actuator Metrics Endpoint not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503571/spring-boot-2-actuator-metrics-endpoint-not-working)

Comment: I was able to enable multiple actuator and the metrics are showing up. How do I enable prometheus to fetch these actuators ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem. Here are the steps:

1. Configure separate acutator ports for each service in application.properties.
2. Expose the configure ports in deployment yaml(in case of kubernetes).

That's it.

Comment: I guess this will not work if >1 POD and each POD has a container for the same application. Wondering how you can get the actuator call to hit multiple PODs all at once. No debate it is a good solution here though